# point-slope form problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Why is the slope not -0.4 like it says in the point-slope form. Isn't the format of the point-slope form y − y1 = m(x − x1) with "m" being slope. The answer says the slope is -2.5, which makes sense after converting to slope-intercept form. But why can't you just take the slope ("m") from the point-slope form?[image: problem and answer]

[image: answer explanation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look again at the problem statement. The equation is given in the form $x-x_0=\frac1m(y-y_0)$, not $y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$. It’s not in point-slope form. It’s a bit of a trick problem meant to test if you’re really paying attention.

Comment: is there any trick to knowing when it is 1/m vs m?

Comment: @user532526 No trick. The slope $m=\Delta y/\Delta x$, so if you swap $x$ and $y$ you end up with $1/m$. Try converting $y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$ into $x-x_0=a(y-y_0)$ for yourself and see what $a$ turns out to be.